# How can I get the Canonical Product Url in list.phtml?

Tags: magento2, product-urls

I need to get Canonical Product Url inside `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`.

I tried to use:

```
$block->getProductUrl($_product)
```

and:

```
$_product->getUrl()
```

but I receive the product url with all the categories while the canonical url has no category. I'm using the Mageworx SEO extension if this can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using:

```
$_product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($_product, ['_ignore_category' => true])
```